# Is there an official Street Fighter canon?

Tags: canon, street-fighter

The announcement of a new [*Street Fighter* TV series](https://www.engadget.com/2018/03/24/a-live-action-street-fighter-tv-show-is-in-development/) got me wondering, what is considered "official" canon in the *"Street Fighter Universe"*? Is there any such thing? My guess is that every property has basically done what they want and there is no single rulebook to follow, but it's possible some effort has been made (by Capcom?) to keep things consistent. Are there tiers or levels like Star Wars used to have?

It's always based around the tournament by [Vega / M. Bison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M._Bison), but each iteration has added new characters and spun it a little differently. Which stories represent the one true Street Fighter timeline?

Comment: I strongly doubt that there's any coherent level of canon based on a video game that came out decades ago and has gone through so many iterations of the characters that I can barely keep up

Comment: http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Movies_%26_Animation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Old Properties (Pre 2016)

In short, it's a great big (and often conflicting) mess but hopefully one that should improve over the next few years with Capcom taking a far greater interest in creating a cohesive 'universe', according to the 'director of publishing' for [Udon Publishing](http://streetfighter.wikia.com/wiki/Street_Fighter_(UDON)), the official publisher of the current Street Fighter magazine.

> **Matt Moylan:** *If it was in a manual maybe or even in a Japanese [manual]. Some people say if it's in the games it's canon but even then like a lot of the
>   games contradict each other. A lot of alpha games have like '**what if**'
>   endings which obviously even within the game can't all make sense so I
>   mean it's hard. **It's really tough to say what is what's canon for
>   street fighter that's why I like the word 'lore' is it can bring in and all these different ideas from different continuities where this [is from] the mangas or the comics or the games or the anime.***
>
> *Maybe even you even asked a Capcom about this before, I know **right now
>   they're kind of trying to make an effort since they started the
>   games again***
>
> <sub><sup>Transcript edited for ease of reading</sup></sub>

---

### New Properties (post 2016)

According to the creator of [Street Fighter: Assassin's Fist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Fighter:_Assassin%27s_Fist) and [Street Fighter: Resurrection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_Fighter:_Resurrection) Joey Ansah, there's now a strict canon that must be adhered to. Character's back-stories need to be observed, even where that canon is "cartoony" or makes zero logical sense. Unfortunately there's no series 'bible' that can be referred to, so the final arbiter of canon is Capcom's liaison with the games and tv show developers.

> **How much liberty do you have when you're writing the story, or do you
>   mostly have to stay within the parameters of Capcom’s existing
>   universe?**
>
> **Joey Ansah:** *My kind of boat is about being true to the canon. I think what pissed a lot of people off about the two movies that came out is that they
>   completely went off-piece and took huge liberties. They were turning
>   it into something else that's no longer Street Fighter. It's a vague
>   interpretation of Street Fighter. It goes without saying that adhering
>   to the canon is a must. And **sometimes the canon that Capcom have
>   created is f%#king ridiculous. I have to be quite inventive to make
>   that work in a believable, intelligent way.** That's part of the fun,
>   part of the challenge. Elements in the Street Fighter story are quite
>   cartoony and not very deep.*
>
> *Capcom trusts me now, which is nice. Resurrection has been the hardest
>   to do, because at least with Assassin's Fist, **there have been anime
>   series and official comic books that have told elements of Ken and
>   Ryu's early years, so there is at least some established canon for
>   what has happened.** When I tried to do Resurrection, which is like a
>   prologue for Street Fighter V and set after Street Fighter IV, there's
>   a big question mark for what has gone on there.*
>
> ...
>
> ***There were things I wanted to put in that I had to change to fit the
>   canon. It was hard because it's not like Capcom gave me a special
>   story book saying here's all the new canon, six or seven months before
>   the game comes out. I had to ask questions and they would say, "Yes,
>   this is canon" or "No, the direction you're going in is counter to the
>   canon." They wouldn't really give specifics.***
>
> <sub><sup>[We chat to Street Fighter: Resurrection director and writer Joey Ansah](https://www.gamespot.com/articles/street-fighter-web-series-director-explains-why-vi/1100-6435655/)</sup></sub>

Joey also offered some additional description of what Capcom consider canon in the Street Fighter universe; the official games, the prologues and epilogues of the games, but not the anime shows, cinematic films or crossover games.

> **This is multi-generational story. We know Ken and Ryu after two
>   decades fighting alongside them. But outside combat, how do you get
>   into their headspace?**
>
> *Where does one begin? ...**We wanted to create the definitive backstory.
>   The story in the Street Fighter universe is very fractured.** You had
>   Street Fighter and that tournament, Ryu beating Sagat at the end, so
>   you've a bit of narrative there. The anime then retro-fitted in that
>   [Sagat] got the scar from Ryu. Then they retro-fitted that in Super
>   Street Fighter II Turbo, Akuma comes in. And they say "okay, he killed
>   Ryu and Ken's master, and was that master's brother". Then there's a
>   long time before Gouken, Ryu and Ken's master, is given a name. So the
>   story's been retro-fitted as its moved forward.*
>
> ***So we've tried to take what's regarded as canon by Capcom, what
>   appears in the prologues and epilogues of the games. The
>   Capcom-endorsed and sanctioned animes, although they are official
>   Capcom stuff, they're not regarded as canon, all of what's in there.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Street Fighter: Assassin's Fist Interview](https://www.gamereactor.eu/articles/87514/Street+Fighter+Assassins+Fist+Interview/)</sup></sub>

Comment: I'm guessing English isn't Matt's first language?

Comment: From the video with Matt above, I'd say you're guessing incorrectly.